# How to implement Java FixedThreadPool using Python multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I need to use a process pool in Python. The requirement is the following:

The pool has a fixed size say 10. I have a number of jobs to submit to the pool (N > 10).
In Java one can use a FixedThreadPool for that purpose. The jobs are submitted, and once a thread finished executing a task the client can submit the next task. So if there are 10 tasks currently running, the client cannot submit the 11th task. But if one completed, the client is able to submit the next task to the available thread.

This is the code I use to test some ideas:

```
import multiprocessing, time


def printStuff(number):
    print number
    if number % 2 : time.sleep(0.5)
    return number*number

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(5, None, None, None)   
a = []

def execute():
    def resultAggregator(n):
        print 'aggregator called...'
        a.append(n)
    for i in range (0, 34):

        # With callback
        #pool.apply_async(printStuff, [i], None, resultAggregator)
        #print "called for ", i

        # Without callback
        res = pool.apply_async(printStuff, [i])
        print "called for" , i, "returned ", res.get()

    pool.close() # disable sumitting any more tasks
    pool.join() # wait for all the worker to finish

execute()
print a
```

res.get() blocks until `printStuff` returns. Using a callback variant doesn't even call `printStuff`. Note in both cases `a` at the end is empty.

Any ideas how to implement the behavior described above? Code snippets would be great, but it is enough a pointer to an existing library function I am not aware of or just toss in some ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about Java's `FixedThreadPool`, but I can fix your code ;-)

You obviously don't want to use `res.get()`, right?  So I'll ignore that part.  The problem with `.apply_async()` is that you're not calling it correctly.  I'm surprised no exception was raised!  The argument list should be a tuple, not a list (as for the builtin `apply()` function).  And for the keyword-args argument, `None` doesn't work.  If you don't have keyword arguments to pass, either leave it out (as I do below) or pass an empty dictionary (`{}`).

Other changes here are more cosmetic:  introduced an IO lock to keep the terminal output from getting scrambled, and introduced a `__name__ == "__main__"` check both for clarity and so that the code will run on Windows too:

```
import multiprocessing, time

def getlock(lck):
    global iolock
    iolock = lck

def printStuff(number):
    with iolock:
        print number
    if number % 2:
        time.sleep(0.5)
    return number*number

def execute():
    def resultAggregator(n):
        with iolock:
            print 'aggregator called...'
        a.append(n)

    for i in range(34):
        pool.apply_async(printStuff, (i,), callback=resultAggregator)
        with iolock:
            print "called for ", i

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = []
    iolock = multiprocessing.Lock()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(5, getlock, (iolock,))   
    execute()
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print a
```

### Later: errors

Turns out an exception actually is raised if you pass `None` for the keyword arguments - but `multiprocessing` suppresses it.  This is, alas, a common problem with asynchronous gimmicks:  there's no good way to raise exceptions!  They occur in a context unrelated to what your "main program" happens to be doing at the time.

At least Python 3.3.2's implementation of `.apply_async()` has an optional `error_callback` argument too.  I don't know when it was introduced.  If you supply it, async exceptions are passed to it, so you can decide how to report (or log, or ignore ...) them.  Adding this function:

```
def ouch(e):
    raise e
```

and changing the invocation to:

```
pool.apply_async(printStuff, (i,), None, resultAggregator, ouch)
```

yields a traceback ending in `ouch()` with this exception detail:

```
TypeError: printStuff() argument after ** must be a mapping, not NoneType
```

So, at least, with a recent enough Python you *can* arrange not to let asynch errors pass invisibly.

### Q&A

> Could you explain the "global iolock" declaration within getLock() ? I thought it
>   defines a global variable for each subprocess, but changing the name from
>   iolock to iiolock in ? "main" makes iolock unknown to the worker processes.

Sorry, I can't tell from that *exactly* what you did.  The name `iolock` is intended to be a global in *all* processes, main and children.  That's because all processes in my code *use* the name `iolock`.

If, for example, "by changing the name ..." you mean you merely replaced

```
iolock = multiprocessing.Lock()
```

to

```
iiolock = multiprocessing.Lock()
```

then you would have got an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(5, getlock, (iolock,))
NameError: global name 'iolock' is not defined
```

If you also changed that line (`pool = ...`) to use `iiolock` too, then you would have gotten a different exception, when `resultAggregator` in the main process tried to use `iolock`:

```
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "mpool.py", line 19, in resultAggregator
    with iolock:
NameError: global name 'iolock' is not defined
```

So I have no idea what you really did.

> Also declaring printStuff within execute causes a silent
>   error (code does not progress past printing "called for")

That can't work.  Functions in Python are not declared - `def` is an *executable* statement.  The code for `printStuff` doesn't exist before `def printstuff` is executed.  Because only the main program executes `execute()`, functions `def`'ed inside `execute()` only exist in the main program.  It's true that

```
    pool.apply_async(printStuff, (i,), callback=resultAggregator)
```

*passes* `printStuff` to the child processes, but all things passed work via pickling on the sending end and unpickling on the receiving end, and function objects cannot be pickled.  Are you sure didn't get an error like this?:

```
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'function'>: attribute lookup builtins.function failed
```

(I'm using Python 3 here - maybe it's different under Python 2).

In any case, Python isn't Java - don't go crazy with nesting - keep it simple ;-)  Every function and class used by a child process should be defined at module level (`class` is also an executable statement in Python! The only "declarations" in Python are the `global` and `nonlocal` statements).

### More Q&A

> You are right about the assumptions. I changed to iiolock in all
>   places except main

Still don't know *exactly* what you did.  For things like this, you really have to post code, not merely describe what you did.  I can only guess otherwise - and that's really painful ;-)  How about this:  if you have a new problem, open a new question?

From what you described here ("in all places except main"), you would have gotten an exception in `execute()`, because the new `iiolock` name would not exist in the main process (which is the only process in which `execute()` runs - and you said you did *not* change the old `iolock` in `main()`).  But you didn't mention an exception, so I *guess* you didn't really do exactly what you said you did ("in all places except main").

> and was expecting that the new Process just get the same lock
>   passed as a param to initialization function but each has its
>   own global iiolock variable. How can multiple processes share
>   the same variable anyway (aren't the memory contents different
>   for each process???).

There are two answers to this ;-)  The one most immediately relevant is that `iolock` (in my original code - I really have no idea what your code looks like now) is an object created by `multiprocessing` (it's an `mp.Lock()`) and passed to child processes via `mp.Pool()` too:

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(5, getlock, (iolock,)) 
                                         ^^^^^^
```

`mp` is in control of everything here, and does a world stuff under the covers to ensure that this `mp.Lock()` has consistent state across processes.  It's not just any old variable, it's something `mp` knows all about and all of whose behavior `mp` implements.

The second answer, which doesn't apply to any of the code in this issue so far, is that you can also create some kinds of data in "shared memory" using `mp`.  See the docs for `mp.Value` and `mp.Array` and `multiprocessing.sharedctypes`.  Those values are truly (physically) shared across processes.

But other than those (objects implemented *by* `mp`, and "shared memory" obtained from `mp`), you're right:  no other values are shared (neither physically nor semantically) across processes.  Communicating all other kinds of object values is done by pickling (serializing) and unpickling (reconstructing an object's value from a pickle string) at various `mp` synchronization points (like when you `.put()` an object on an `mp.Queue`, and another process `.get()`s it).

Comment: Perfect answer ! It seems to do exactly what I want.

Comment: @Eugen, you were very close already! Passing args in a list (instead of a tuple) actually works, but since that's undocumented (except that it appears in some examples) better to stick with the tuple spelling. The only "real" problem in your code was passing `None` :-)

Comment: Could you explain the "global iolock" declaration within getLock() ? I thought it defines a global variable for each subprocess, but changing the name from iolock to iiolock in "__main__" makes iolock unknown to the worker processes. Also declaring printStuff within execute causes a silent error (code does not progress past printing "called for")

Comment: @Eugen, please see my edit just now - couldn't fit in a comment.

Comment: You are right about the assumptions. I changed to iiolock in all places except __main__ and was expecting that the new Process just get the same lock passed as a param to initialization function but each has its own global iiolock variable. How can multiple processes share the same variable anyway (aren't the memory contents different for each process???). Regarding the nesting you are right again, I was getting the weird PicklingError and I had no idea what to do with it.

Comment: @Eugen, see "More Q&A" at the end.  Please open a new issue with new code if stuff is still unclear.

Comment: Most things are clear to me now. I changed iolock to iilock only in getLock() and printStuff() (sorry no code :) ) and it works as I expect (I apply the changes to the code posted by you). Finally I understood the pickling error. printStuff() is simply not known outside execute() and thus to other processes. You mentioned that function objects cannot be pickled but how then the printStuff() defined outside execute() is being passed to the process? I would upvote 3 times the answer but unfortunately SO allows only one upvote :)

Comment: Progress ;-)  `printStuff()` doesn't have to be passed, because it's defined at module level - *every* process sees it automatically.  On Linux-y systems, because it was already defined when `mp` forks, and on Windows because each child process imports the "main program" as a module (so re-executes all the code in the module).  Likewise `execute()` is *known* to all processes, but only the main program actually calls it.